# IBM Bluemix natural language understanding API

Tags: nlp, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson

I want to start the Watson **IBM Bluemix Natural Language Understanding** (test version) but when creating such an instance online (Free service as the website indicates) I get the error '*The service instance is invalid: not a valid service plan*':

Could you anyone elaborate a bit on how to fix this or if this is due to the test version I am using?

Answer (score 1):

You can provision the **Natural Language Understanding** on Bluemix using this link:

https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/natural-language-understanding

After visiting the link, you will arrive at this page:

[image: page]

Click **Create** to create a new service instance with the Free Plan.

After clicking **Create**, it will provision an instance of the service which should look like this:

[image: provisioned nlu]

If you have any issues with this process, you should contact Bluemix support.

Comment: Thanks, Joe! Yes, that is what I was doing, but when clicking 'Create' the aforementioned error message pops up. I contacted several times the Bluemix support but have not received any answer yet... Many thanks though!

Comment: What region are you logged into?

Comment: So are you logged into the `eu-de` region on Bluemix (or `ng`, `eu-gb`, etc.)?

Comment: As far as I know the Germany region (`eu-de`) is fairly new and does not have the **Natural Language Understanding** service. I've never got that error before that you got and was able to provision fine in the Dallas US region (`ng`).

Comment: Same issue for me with cloudant service. Did you find a solution ?

Comment: I did not find a solution, but I suppose that the issue is due to our location that is not the US...